# When using Spring + Spring Boot + STS, where in the Spring Project directory is the localhost "home" folder?

Tags: spring, ember.js, spring-boot

I am using Spring/Spring Boot/and Ember. I want to put my index.html file in the "localhost" main folder, but I have no idea how the Spring Tool Suite deploys Spring Boot. What is the normal process for HTML development and accessing a Spring REST server without getting Cross Site Scripting errors?

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/.settings
/BookingClient
/gradle
/html  (this is where my index.html, css, and all Ember related JS stuff is)
/node_modules
/src
/target
```

I am guessing its somewhere in the /target directory but nothing I have tried has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot will serve static resources for you. Simply put them in `src/main/resources/static`. See the [documentation on static content](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) for more information.

Comment: Its not working for some reason. I created this folder: 'workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1\BookingSoftware2\src\main\resources\static' and put a simple html file in there called test.html. I then tried: 'http://localhost:8080/test.html' and got this error: 'There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).'

Comment: I figured it out! Its NOT in the static folder. For me, the src/main/webapp folder did the trick. Your answer led me to that conclusion though so i really appreciate the help!